# How to put default value in query to Android ContentProvider

Tags: android, null, android-contentprovider

I'm writing a simple music app for Android 2.1 and stumbled upon such a problem:

In my Activity I have a ListView, which has album cover, album title, artist and number of songs in each row. I query the ContentProvider for all those values to put in the ListView. But some albums on SDCARD have no album cover and the query returns NULL I think. In result in my ListView I have albums where only few have covers.

What I would like to do, is to put some argument when querying ContentProvider or in some other place, to put my default icon as album cover if the query returns null cover. I mean, if the ContentProvider returns nothing as a cover, I would like to put my default icon in this place.

Maybe I should use some other query, not by ManagedCursor?

I saw solution to similar db problem using the IFNULL clause (SELECT IFNULL(title, "------") AS title FROM books;). I thought it could help in some way, but there is no place to put such a clause in ContentProvider query.

Does anyone know how to do it? I put mu code below:

```
private void getAllAlbumsFromSDCARD() 
{
    String[] cols = { MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, 
            MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS};        
    Uri allAlbumsUri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    albumsCursor = this.managedQuery(allAlbumsUri, cols, null, null, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
    // SELECT IFNULL(title, "------") AS title FROM books;
    Log.d(TAG, "" +albumsCursor.getCount());

    if(albumsCursor!=null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Managing cursor");
        startManagingCursor(albumsCursor);

        //  
        String[] from = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART, MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, 
                MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.cover, R.id.album, R.id.artist, R.id.count };

        ListAdapter albums = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.album_row, albumsCursor, from, to);
        this.setListAdapter(albums);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that solution for my problem is custom CursorAdapter. I paste a code that makes exactly what I wanted:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

private MainActivity mainActivity;
private int layout;

public MyCursorAdapter(MainActivity context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    this.mainActivity = context;
    this.layout = layout;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     // Cursor to current item 
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    cursor.moveToPosition(position);

    View v = mainActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false); 

    TextView albumTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.album); 
    if (albumTV != null) 
    { 
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM); 
            String album = cursor.getString(index); 
            albumTV.setText(album); 
    } 

    TextView artistTV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.artist); 
    if (artistTV != null) 
    { 
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST); 
            String artist = cursor.getString(index); 
            artistTV.setText(artist); 
    } 

    TextView countTV = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.count); 
    if (countTV != null) 
    { 
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS); 
            String count = cursor.getString(index); 
            countTV.setText(count); 
    }

    ImageView cover = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cover); 
    if (cover != null) 
    { 
            int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART);
            String path = cursor.getString(index); 
            Log.d("MCA", ""+path);

            if(path == null)
            {
                cover.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_cover_64);
                cover.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            }
            else 
            {
                BitmapDrawable icon = new BitmapDrawable(path);
                cover.setImageDrawable(icon);
            }
    } 
    return v; 
}
```

}